# Squid Proxy Block it RDP Connections, Solution?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, proxy, iptables, squid

This is my scenario:

[image: Scenario]

I create my blocking rules inside the Squid proxy to block pages and ports. And my problem is that when I want to connect to a Windows Remote Desktop via IP, it doesn't connect me, it adds the public IP and port 3389 and still doesn't connect me. So reading I saw that this could be a solution you have to create an iptab which redirects the traffic to the port that uses the RDP to the proxy and I'm doing this.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $INTERFAZ_LAN -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination $SQUID_SERVER_IP
```

I read this:

> Squid handles requests and responses from web protocols such as HTTP and HTTPS, squid is not designed to handle other types of traffic, such as remote desktop protocol (RDP) traffic using port 3389.
>
> RDP traffic is a completely different protocol than HTTP and HTTPS, and is not normally handled through a web proxy such as Squid. Squid is generally not able to inspect and forward RDP traffic in the same way it does HTTP/HTTPS traffic.